# How to load multiple OCaml files into toplevel?

Tags: module, ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, toplevel

I'm trying to debug a program I made. This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
src
 |- module1.ml
 |- section1
     |- module2.ml
     |- module3.ml
```

module1.ml is referenced by both module2.ml and module3.ml. module2.ml is referenced by module3.ml.

I've tried loading the files into the toplevel with the command

```
ocaml -I section1 module1.ml section1/module2.ml section1/module3.ml
```

but it doesn't work. It doesn't even bring up the toplevel or print an error. It does absolutely nothing and I am back to where I started with the Bash prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run your code in this fashion, you're limited by the fact that the `ocaml` command expects any number of pre-compiled OCaml files (bytecode files) and one `.ml` file. If you supply multiple `.ml` files it ignores all but the first.

The reason for your observed behavior is that your command line is asking for `ocaml` to run a file as a program. In other words, it's going to execute all the top-level code in the first `.ml` file (ignoring the rest) and then exit. I assume you don't have any top-level code that produces a visible result in your `module1.ml` file.

You can make this work (or at least improve the situation) by compiling all but one of the files using `ocamlc`:

```
$ ocamlc -c section1/module2.ml
$ ocamlc -c section2/module3.ml
$ ocaml section1/module2.cmo section1/module3.cmo module1.ml
```

You can also load files into the toplevel after starting it up:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.10.0

# #use "section1/module2.ml";;
# #use "section1/module3.ml";;
# #use "module1.ml";;
#
```

This is what I usually do to experiment interactively with my code.

If I just want to *run* the code, on the other hand, I compile all the files and then just run the result:

```
$ ocamlc -o myprogram section1/module2.ml section1/module3.ml module1.ml
$ ./myprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer you have been given, if you want to load modules from the top level without compiling the modules, you can use the `#mod_use` directive, added I believe in ocaml-4.01.  It behaves in a similar way to the #use directive, except that your code appears as if it were a compiled module (so the filename becomes an initial module name).

See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#s%3Atoplevel-directives